# Application autostart after system boot for a random interval

Tags: boot, bash, autostart, sleep, startup-applications

Reading 'sleep' mans and googling haven't provide any useful information.

I want to run Pidgin after Ubuntu boots, but after some time left. For example, logon is passed, and after interval for 1 to 5 minutes Pidgin starts. As manuals of 'sleep' says, there a way to specify only number of hours, mins and seconds.

Is there any way/other linux command to solve my problem?

Comment: Why does it have to be a random interval?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want it, but you can do what you want with the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
interval=$(( ($RANDOM % 5) + 1))
sleep ${interval}m
(pidgin) &
exit
```

It picks a number 1-5 and then sleeps for that many minutes, then starts pidgin in the background and exits the script.